# PyQt5 и threading - запуск и остановка потоков кнопкой

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread

Пример: имеется программа, которая при нажатии на кнопку "старт" начинает выполнять несколько непрерывных циклов одновременно в отдельных потоках, которые при нажатии на ту же кнопку останавливаются.

Как реализовать остановку в виде:

- 1. Резкого прерывания.
- 2. "Безопасного" прерывания (цикл доходит до конца и останавливается).
- 3. Прерывания с "чекпоинтами" (в цикле несколько заданных возможных мест для выхода, которое выбирается исходя из места в коде, где была нажата кнопка).

---

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from funs import function1, function2, function3


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 261, 91))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)


    def start(self):
        global working
        if self.pushButton.text() == 'Начать':
            self.pushButton.setText('Стоп')
            working = True
            function1().start()
            function2().start()
            function3().start()
        else:
            self.pushButton.setText('Начать')
            working = False



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    working = False

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**funs.py**:

```
import threading
import time

class function1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for n in range(6):
                print(n)
                time.sleep(1)
            print()


class function2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for n in range(10, 16):
                print(n)
                time.sleep(2)
            print()

class function3(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('Привет!')
            print('Я')
            time.sleep(5)
            # Чекпоинт
            print('вывожу')
            print('слова')
            time.sleep(5)
            # Чекпоинт
            print('через')
            print('время')
            time.sleep(5)
            # Чекпоинт
```

Comment: Используйте кутэшные потоки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю вам попробовать следующий вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#import threading
#import time

#from funs import function1, function2, function3
class Function1(QtCore.QThread):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.working = True

    def run(self):
        self.dataChanged.emit("Start Function1")
        while self.working:
            for n in range(6):
                self.dataChanged.emit(f"Data Function1: {n}")
                self.msleep(1000)
                if not self.stoped():
                    break
        self.finished.emit(f"finished Function1: {n} -------")

    def stoped(self): 
        return self.working


class Function2(QtCore.QThread):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.working = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for n in range(10, 16):
                print(n)
                time.sleep(2)

    def run(self):
        self.dataChanged.emit("Start  Function  22")
        while self.working:
            for n in range(10, 16):
                self.dataChanged.emit(f"Data  Function  22: {n}")
                self.msleep(1000)
            if not self.stoped():
                break
        self.finished.emit(f"finished  Function  22: {n} -------")

    def stoped(self): 
        return self.working


class Function3(QtCore.QThread):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.working = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            n = 'Привет! Я '
            self.dataChanged.emit(f"Data  Function  333: {n}")
            self.msleep(3000)
            # Чекпоинт
            if not self.stoped():
                break
            n = 'вывожу слова '
            self.dataChanged.emit(f"Data  Function  333: {n}")
            self.msleep(3000)
            # Чекпоинт
            if not self.stoped():
                break
            n = 'через время'
            self.dataChanged.emit(f"Data  Function  333: {n}")
            self.msleep(3000)
            # Чекпоинт
            if not self.stoped():
                break
        self.finished.emit(f"finished  Function  333: {n} -------")        

    def stoped(self): 
        return self.working


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(165, 270, 70, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 380, 250))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.function1 = Function1()
        self.function1.dataChanged.connect(self.dataThreads)
        self.function1.finished.connect(self.finishThreads)
        self.function2 = Function2()
        self.function2.dataChanged.connect(self.dataThreads)
        self.function2.finished.connect(self.finishThreads)        
        self.function3 = Function3()
        self.function3.dataChanged.connect(self.dataThreads)
        self.function3.finished.connect(self.finishThreads)  

    def start(self):
        if self.pushButton.text() == 'Начать':
            self.pushButton.setText('Стоп')
            self.function1.working = True
            self.function1.start()
            self.function2.working = True
            self.function2.start()            
            self.function3.working = True
            self.function3.start() 
        else:
            self.pushButton.setText('Начать')
            self.function1.working = False
            self.function2.working = False
            self.function3.working = False

    def dataThreads(self, text):
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text)

    def finishThreads(self, text):
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]